# Film: Secret world behind a bookcase- ageing prevents access

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to identify a story/filmstrip in which the main character (boy/girl?) can access a secret world behind a bookcase. I seem to remember it being one child, not a group like *Narnia*. As they age, they are more and more restricted from visiting, until a final visit. It was set in the mid-70s era/period.

Comment: Sounds like Narnia. If that's not it, please try adding answers from the checklist to your Question: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337

Comment: No, I seem to remember it being one child, and set in the mid-70s era/period.

Comment: It's ringing faint bells. Was it a British kids TV show?

Comment: I don't remember it as a British show, although it very well could be a British special.  My vague memory is that to access the alternate world, one had to crawl behind a bookcase and through a small panel/door.  When the protagonist was too big to fit through the door, they could no longer enter.